# Jquery/JS - POST - Mobile Issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, apache, mobile

I am having trouble understanding the following error.

I have a basic form.

```
<form action="demo_form" method="POST" .... >
  //.... a bunch of dynamic items (it's a shopping cart)
  <button id="submit-button" type="submit" >Check Out</button>
</form>
```

When I click submit, I show a little loading animation. There is a slight hang before my check is posted,this is just to show the application is responding. I also disable the button after the first click, in an effort to prevent resubmission/erros.

This is my JS code, every things works fine across IE/Edge/Chrome/Firefox:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#submit-button").attr("disabled", false);
        $("#submit-button").click(function () {
            $('#ajax-wait').modal('show'); // show loading indicator
            $(this).attr("disabled", true);
        });
    });
```

However, this was not working on any mobile device. It would just hang. The post would send. But no action would be taken on the response. I went over and over this, i followed it through my network debugger. I could not for the life of me figure out what was happenging. Successfuly POSTs eveytime but no responce. Just on mobile.

I eventually started debugging through my code, and ended up commenting out the following line in that little piece of JS.

```
   $(this).attr("disabled", true);
```

So my code now looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#submit-button").attr("disabled", false);
        $("#submit-button").click(function () {
            $('#ajax-wait').modal('show'); // show loading indicator
            //$(this).attr("disabled", true);
        });
    });
```

How is it that disabling the submit button, after it has been clicked, prevented my any response from my server. AND only on mobile.

Can anyone explain to me why this would just hang on mobile, and not desktop browsers?

I cant figure it out.
I should also note that there were no JS errors being logged to the console either. Everything appeared to be working.

Here is the network traffic being posted:

[image]
Thanks,